# Android Studio 1.1.0 Logcat empty

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

For some reason, more often than not when trying to debug my app the logcat in Android Studio is empty. If I open Android Device Monitor the logcat in there works.

In the left hand window where devices are listed, it is showing "No debuggable applications"

Has anyone else experienced this and or overcome it?

Android Studio:
[image: Android Studio]

Android Device Monitor:
[image: Android Device Monitor]

Comment: Are you setting a filter on accident?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the full logcat view in Android studio?

Comment: This may sound silly, but I have run into this before and doing a full reboot of my pc fixed the issue. Not sure if it will help in your case.

Comment: trying pressing the lowest button on the logcat bar, the one with the green arrow coming out of a square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonny, what usually works for me is pressing this button right here:
[image: answer]

or you can always use "/platform-tools/adb logcat" as a workaround!